# Please recommend an optimized IP lookup algorithm and data structs

Tags: algorithm

I've built a geoip database with around 8,000,000 IP segments. In order to load it into memory for fast lookup, I tried to use std::map as a interval tree. The lookup speed is around 20-40us each with random IPv4 address, but far beyond the project requirement(< 10 us each).I appreciate someone can suggest a better alternative on this, thanks.

```
// the geoip info attach to each ip segment
struct geoip_info {
    geoip_info(const geoip_info& info);
    uint32_t country;
    uint32_t subdiv;
    uint32_t city;
    float    latitude;
    float    longitude;
};

// the ip segment definition used as the std::map key
struct ip_segment_key {
    uint32_t from;
    uint32_t to;
    ip_segment_key(uint32_t from, uint32_t to);
    ip_segment_key(const ip_segment_key& key);
    bool operator==(const ip_segment_key & data) const;
    bool operator!=(const ip_segment_key & data) const;
    bool operator>(const ip_segment_key & data) const;
    bool operator<(const ip_segment_key & data) const;
};

struct lookup_table {
    // use std::map as a interval tree here
    typedef std::map<ip_segment_key , geoip_info> ip_range_map;
    ip_range_map table;

    void load(uint32_t ip_range_from, uin32_t ip_range_to, geoip_info &info) {
        table.insert(make_pair(ip_segment_key(from, to), value));    
    }

    // lookuping ip means passing a key with same 'from' and 'to' as the ip argument
    bool lookup(uint32_t ip, geoip_info &info) {
        auto it = table.find(ip_segment(ip, ip);
        if (it != table.end()) {
            info = it->second;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code you write.

Comment: please include what code/language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd say that's a question of available memory...

if you happen to have 4 gigs of ram for this, it can easily be a O(1) lookup in the end...

if you partition your your segments into multiple trees based on a method that can easily identify which tree to search, you can get trees with no more than 2,000,000 elements which should be in the range you are looking for ... n-bit-prefixes could be such a method ... what exactly depends on the shape of your data set

Answer (score 0):

For your 8M IP subnets, you can create 128mb hashtable, contains 16M of uint64_t values. Each value is:

- bytes 0-3 - IP prefix of segment
- byte 4 - netmask (0-32)
- bytes 5-7 - 24-bit data value for your geolocation

Search/Insert into thus table can be performed by key, contains 5 lowest bytes, i.e. by IP+netmask.

For given address, just iterate masks from 0 to 31, and each time lookup your hashtable. I think, all 31 searches total would consume less than 5us. My own implementation for double hash performs each search for ~120ns, so in worst case you will spend only 4us.
Practically, you will reach result more quick, so real average lookup time I estimated is 1-2us.